# Javascript infinity division

Tags: javascript, infinity

I can see in my code that

```
console.log(Infinity/0) // Infinity
```

But

```
console.log(Infinity/Infinity) // NaN
```

I can assume that the reasons are in mathematics, but i can't find any explanations related to JS.

Can someone point me to some articles?

Comment: Maybe this is something? Read: http://www.2ality.com/2012/02/nan-infinity.html

Comment: In addition to Joe's answer, it makes sense in mathematical terms as well. Infinity plus, minus, multiplied, divided by a constant is infinity. Infinity divided by itself cancels itself out and is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Here [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.2) it says:

> The result of division is determined by the specification of IEEE 754 arithmetic
>
> Division of an infinity by a zero results in an infinity. The sign is determined by the rule already stated above.

and

> Division of an infinity by an infinity results in NaN.

It's in the spec, so that's what it does. Why does it do it? Read IEEE 754 or this [Wikipedia page on IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is a special case that can't be equal to anything not even itself .it is used  when a operation results in a mathematically undefined value.

ex:

```
console.log(NaN === NaN); // false
console.log(0 / 0);     // NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript follows [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) specification for doing arithmetic. [This table](http://www.iki.fi-jhi.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/infnan.html) shows Infinity arithmetic rules.